# Fingers do not move when i move right hand

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

There is no problem when i move left hand, but some of fingers do not move when i move right hand.

Perhaps the solution is weight paint. I do not find which bones have this problem.

here is the.blend file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/52tphkvo7vacui6/2b_09_question.blend?dl=0

here is a video that show the problem: https://youtu.be/Y4uAtzpHC8s

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have accidentally deleted a bone, which was responsible for the ring finger R bones to move (the weights are OK: if you move the deforming ring R Bone, the mesh follows). As this rig is quite complex, probably the simplest way to fix the problem is to delete the rig and generate a new one: then select the mesh and add an armature modifier, choosing the new rig as object: if the names are the same the weights will be already OK.
This case explains why it is useful not to delete the metarig.

[image]

Comment: Thanks josh sanfelici. My problem is completely resolved.